# Android Webview -> Uncaught Security Error while setting values in localStorage of webview

Tags: javascript, android, dom, webview, android-webview

I need to load a webview in android by setting some properties in local and session storage.

I tried to save values in local / session storage with the help of `webView.evaluateJavascript("window.localStorage.setItem('$key','$val1');", null)`   for which I am getting the below error.

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

```html
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.settings.databaseEnabled = true
        webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true 
        webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true

  webView.evaluateJavascript("window.localStorage.setItem('$key','$val1');", null) 
     webView.loadUrl("url to load")
```

I have also set `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in manifest .

Is there any suggestion for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

First add these lines

```
websettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); // Turn on DOM storage
websettings.setAllowFileAccess(true); // can read the file cache
websettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true); //Enable H5 (APPCache) caching
```

And Then

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
  webView.evaluateJavascript("window.localStorage.setItem('"+ key +"','"+ val +"');", null);
} else {
  webView.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.setItem('"+ key +"','"+ val +"');");
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your feedback.
I tried the above code it gives me the same error 
"Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document."

Comment: Yes added
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: add these permissions in manifest and in your code also on App start

Comment: No Luck with them

Answer (score 0):

I do realize it's an old question, but just do it later. the Page isn't loaded yet so it doesn't know it's http:// or https:// or the site name to work as the context for the change.

When going back() in the webview this can cause problems when doing it at the callback for when the page is loaded as when going back on android it isn't called, but you need to redo your injection regardless.

The lack of control over the storage through the provided means from WebView on android are now really unfortunate.